# Undetermined Coefficients, finding $y$ complementary.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''''+2y''+y=\cos(x)$ This is the equation I am trying to solve

My approach:

$r^4+2r+1=0$

$(r^2+1)^2=0$

$r_1=r_3=+i, r_2=r_4=-i$
This means (I think) my $Y_h=c_1cos(x)+c_2sin(x)+c_3xcos(x)+c_4xsin(x)$

Does this mean my y complimentary will be: 
$ yc(x)=Ax^2cos(x)+Bx^2sin(x)+Cxcos(x)+Dxsin(x)$
 Since $cos(x)$ is a solution, and it already repeats in $y_h$?

There's also another equation I am trying to solve
$y''+2y'+2=x^2e^{-x}cos(x)$

My approach:
$r^2+r+2=0$

$r_1=-1+i, r_2=-1-i$
$y_h=e^{-x}(cos(x)+sin(x))$

Here will my $y_c$ is going to be $y_c=(Ax^2+Bx+C)(e^{-x})(\cos(x)+\sin(x))$

or is it going to be $y_c=(x)(Ax^2+Bx+C)(e^{-x})(\cos(x)+\sin(x))$
Since $(e^{-x})$ repeats in $y_h$?

Comment: Need to multiply by x again. Don't want any piece of homogeneous solution in particular solution. Process is to form particular solution first ignoring homogeneous solution, then multiply by large enough power of x to make it so that no part of the particular is part of the homogeneous.

Comment: It's just $x^2(A \sin(x)+B \cos(x))$.

Comment: @jdods Thanks I see it now. How about my yp for my second question?

Comment: Yes, you need the extra x because of the constant C term. Try both, differentiating fully and plugging in to see what happens. Tedious work, but should be instructive.

Comment: @jdods Great, thank you so much.